# Align markers under a div using css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add 9 markers under a common `div` and adding name for each `div`. The code works well, when I am using a 100% width of the page. I would like to adjust it to 80%.Now I see that the markers are not aligned properly with the main div.

My code:

```css
.wrap {
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin:auto;
  border:1px solid black;
  height:100px;
  padding:10px;
}

.amntslider {
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  width: calc(100% / 9 * 8 + 2px);
  margin:auto;
}


.Mark{
  font-size: 18px;
  width: calc(100% / 9);
  float: left;  
}

.L {
  
  font-size: 10px;
  width: calc(99% / 9);
  float: left;
  text-align:left;
  margin:auto;
}

.MarkWrap {margin:auto;}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">

<div id="amntslider" class="amntslider"></div>
<div class="MarkWrap">

<div class="Mark">|</div>
<div class="Mark">|</div>
<div class="Mark">|</div>
<div class="Mark">|</div>
<div class="Mark">|</div>
<div class="Mark">|</div>
<div class="Mark">|</div>
<div class="Mark">|</div>
<div class="Mark">|</div>

<div class="L">0L</div>
<div class="L">25L</div>
<div class="L">50L</div>
<div class="L">75L</div>
<div class="L">100L</div>
<div class="L">125L</div>
<div class="L">150L</div>
<div class="L">175L</div>
<div class="L">200L</div>

</div>

</div>
```

I have added a main div `MarkWrap` for the marker and test and tried to use `margin:auto;` thinking that will center the entire thing, just like the slider div, but that is not working. Can you suggest what is the problem with the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about an easier way to re-create this with less of code where you can easily adjust anything:

```css
.wrap {
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.MarkWrap {
  width:60%; /*Adjust this to adjust the width*/
  margin: auto;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  /* to illustrate*/
  animation:width-change 2s alternate infinite linear;
}
.amntslider {
  background:red;
  height:15px;
  flex-basis:100%;
  margin:0 calc((100% / 9) / 2);
}

.L {
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-top:15px;
  flex:1;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
}
.L:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  height:10px;
  bottom:100%;
  width:1px;
  left:calc(50% - 1px);
  background:#000;
}

@keyframes width-change {
  from {
    width:60%;
  }
  to {
    width:80%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<div class="MarkWrap">
    <div class="amntslider"></div>
    <div class="L">0L</div>
    <div class="L">25L</div>
    <div class="L">50L</div>
    <div class="L">75L</div>
    <div class="L">100L</div>
    <div class="L">125L</div>
    <div class="L">150L</div>
    <div class="L">175L</div>
    <div class="L">200L</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: :   How can I adjust the height of the marker? I would like to increase the length of it

Comment: @acr it's the top value actually they are 10px so make this value bigger and adjust the margin-top of `.L` to aboid overflow

Comment: @acr i edit the answer to make it height instead of top, so it's easier ;)

Comment: If I want to change the marker counter, say 7, how will I adjust it. I tried to change the code margin:0 calc((100% / 7) / 2); but markers are not aligning.

Comment: :sorry, I messed up the code last time and its working as expected, but there is a length difference between the sliders. I have to use more than 4 slider in my page and each will have different marker count. I believe I can use individual .MarkWrap and adjust the length..Is there any better way to do it ? here is the sample https://jsfiddle.net/anoopcr/468vu1jp/

Comment: @acr yes there is a lenght difference because they are not the same size, so you have to adjust the width ... and you can keep only on class and use CSS variable, you can adjust without having to add more classes with the same properties

Answer (score 0):

I think it will make more sense do do such way:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

.wrap {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.linear {
  width: calc(100% / 9 * 8 + 2px);
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.amntslider {
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 60%;
  animation: filling 3s alternate infinite ease-in-out;
}

.MarkWrap {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.l {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: calc(100% / 8 - 1px);
  height: 20px;
}
.l:last-child {
  margin-right: -2px;
}
.l span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  white-space: nowrap;
}

@keyframes filling {
  from {
    width: 0%;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="linear">
    <div class="amntslider" id="amntslider"></div>
    <div class="MarkWrap">
      <div class="l"><span>0 l</span></div>
      <div class="l"><span>25 l</span></div>
      <div class="l"><span>50 l</span></div>
      <div class="l"><span>75 l</span></div>
      <div class="l"><span>100 l</span></div>
      <div class="l"><span>125 l</span></div>
      <div class="l"><span>150 l</span></div>
      <div class="l"><span>175 l</span></div>
      <div class="l"><span>200 l</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: as a side note: the question it not about the animation, it's about centring ... i used the animation to illustrate the variation of the width and to show that it remains centred